# Why doesnt' my bootstrap work on specific pages?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm doing some school homework right and am creating a PHP site. I'm using an HTML template demo as my template, however, after some editing, certain pages won't load bootstrap properly unlike the others. Here are screenshots of the site:

[image]

While on another page they load properly.

[image]

Also, before I sign in, my modal had no container.

[image]

It will be a great pleasure for me if anyone would be able to help me.

Thanks in advance!

edit: i didnt know what or where it went wrong so i upload my whole project here : https://github.com/ch182/spp

Comment: are you seeing any console errors in pages where bootstrap is not working?

Comment: @SubSul it was slow connection error at first, but when i click the link provided by browser its gone now